# Select part of a field's value mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, explode

I have a database field which contains a value in a very specific format.

When I perform this following basic sql query:

```
SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts LIMIT 5
```

It returns the following resultset:

```
[download id="5219"]
[download id="953"]
[download id="958"]
[download id="3907"]
[download id="3909"]
```

I need to edit the query so that it only returns the numeric value of the string. So - instead of returning: `[download id="5219"]` , I want it to return `5219`

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If that’s some kind of BBCode, try the [built-in BBCode functions](http://php.net/book.bbcode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `substring_index()`.  The following will return the value as a number:

```
select substring_index(post_content, '"', 2) + 0
```

The following as a string:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(post_content, '"', 2), '"', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pattern is always `[download id="x"]` where you only want to take `x`, you can replace `[download id="` and `"]` with an empty string using [MySQL REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(post_content,'[download id="',''),'"]','') AS post_content 
FROM wp_posts LIMIT 5
```